# TypeScript includes files it shouldn't include?

Tags: typescript

I have a tsconfig like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

and let's say a very simple source file:

```
// ./src/index.ts
function hello() {
  return 'hello';
}
```

then somehow, I get the error message:

```
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts:41:6 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'.

41 type IteratorResult<T, TReturn = any> = IteratorYieldResult<T> | IteratorReturnResult<TReturn>;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../../node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:166:11
    166 interface IteratorResult<T> { }
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'IteratorResult' was also declared here.
```

Now I know about the other StackOverflow post with the same error message, but this is not actually the same error. Why does it check `../../../node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:166:11`? I'm only including `src`?

I don't have the same problem when I'm using `"module": "commonjs"`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for the `typings` a different rule applies than the `"include"`. You need to add the `typeRoots` property to your tsconfig compiler options:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types/"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Otherwise it travels up to search for the types as specified here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your
>   compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder
>   are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within
>   ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/,
>   ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.